Show that $\pi_1(T^2 \# RP^2) \cong \mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z}_2$.
I'm required to find $\pi_1(T^2 \# RP^2)$. So, to calculate the fundamental group of $ T^2 \# RP^2 $, we will use the fact that the connected sum is a construction that allows us to compute the fundamental group by applying the Seifert-van Kampen theorem.
We decompose $ T^2 \# RP^2 $ into the spaces $ U_1 = T^2 - D_1^2 $ and $ U_2 = RP^2 - D_2^2 $, where $ D_1^2 \subset T^2 $ and $ D_2^2 \subset RP^2 $ are closed disks, and $ \pi_1(U_1 \cap U_2) \cong \pi_1(S^1) \cong \mathbb{Z} $.
We note that the fundamental group of $ U_1 = T^2 - D_1^2 $ is the fundamental group of a torus with a disk removed, which is isomorphic to the free group on two generators: $ \pi_1(T^2 - D_1^2) \cong \langle a, b \rangle \cong \mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z} $. This is because the removed disk introduces a boundary (which is a circle), and we no longer enforce the commutator relation on the loops around the two circles in the torus. Essentially, the group of loops around the two original circles no longer "close up" to form a commutator, because there's now a hole in the surface.
Similarly, the fundamental group of $ U_2 = RP^2 - D_2^2 $ is isomorphic to the fundamental group of $ RP^2 $ with a disk removed. This is, because any loop that was non-trivial in $ RP^2 $ (requiring two traversals to be contracted) remains non-trivial in $ RP^2 - D_2^2 $.
The fundamental group of $ T^2 \# RP^2 $ is the amalgamated free product of $ \pi_1(U_1) $ and $ \pi_1(U_2) $ over $ \pi_1(U_1 \cap U_2) \cong \mathbb{Z} $. This means we identify the generator of the subgroup $ \mathbb{Z} $ in $ \pi_1(U_1) $ (which we can assume is $ a $, one of the generators of $ \mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z} $, let's say $a$ and $b$) with the generator of the subgroup $ \mathbb{Z} $ in $ \pi_1(U_2) $ (which we can assume is $ c $).
Therefore, the fundamental group of $ T^2 \# RP^2 $ has the following presentation:
$$ \pi_1(T^2 \# RP^2) \cong \langle a, b, c \mid c^2 = 1, a = c \rangle $$
By substituting $ a = c $ into the relation $ c^2 = 1 $, we obtain $ a^2 = 1 $. Thus, the simplified presentation of the fundamental group is:
$$ \pi_1(T^2 \# RP^2) \cong \langle a, b \mid a^2 = 1 \rangle $$
The proof was inspired on
What is the fundamental group of $RP^2\#T$, the real projective space of dimension 2 and T is a torus?

Edit
Here is a complementary post:
Van Kampen's Theorem with Torus and Projective Plane

but I don't clearly see why we were speaking about the conmutator subgroup. So, is the proof that I wrote correct?

Your calculation is wrong, this fundamental group is not a free product.

You make a mistake when identifying the generators with one another. You have a loop representing the generator of $\pi_1(U_1\cap U_2)$, which is precisely the boundary of the open disk you have removed from $T^2$ resp. $RP^2$. What does the image of this loop represent in $\pi_1(U_1)$ or $\pi_1(U_2)$? (The linked answer explains this, too.)

@Thorgott We have a loop $\alpha$ representing the generator of $\pi_1(U_1 \cap U_2)$ which is precisely the boundary of the open disk we have removed from $T^2$ and $RP^2$. In the case of $T^2$, we have that $\alpha$ is homotopic to $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$, where $T^2 = \langle a, b: ab= ba \rangle$ which induces the amalgamated relation $1 = aba^{-1}b^{-1}$. By the other hand, since antipodal points are identified in $RP^2$, $\alpha$ is homotopic to $c^2$ which induces the amalgamated relation $1 = c^2$. Thus, $\pi_1(T^2 # RP^2) = \langle a,b,c: c^2 = [a, b] \rangle$. Right?

@BlueTomato Almost, you identify the images of the loop correctly, but you don't get two relations $1=aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ and $1=c^2$ separately. You simply get $c^2=[a,b]$ (as you write at the end), but this element is not trivial. Otherwise the group would just be $\mathbb{Z}^2$.
